# Why does $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x}}$ equal $x^{3/4}$ instead of $x^{1/4}$?

Tags: radicals

When I try to solve the equation, I get $x^{1/4}$ since the two roots share the same index and exponent, which means that I ought to be able to multiply across.

Instead, the solution in the textbook is as follows.

$$\left (xx^{1/2} \right )^{1/2}=\left ( x^{3/2} \right )^{1/2}=x^{3/4}$$

Where did $x^{3/2}$ come from? I can't figure out how I get a 3 from any of that. And why is my original intuition incorrect?

Comment: @YiFan Thanks for the edit. New to this.

Comment: No problem; please check that I haven't accidentally changed the meaning.

Comment: $4\cdot4^{1/2}=4\cdot2=4^{3/2}=8$

Comment: @YiFan, that's the way that I wanted to write it, just couldn't figure out how to make the first square root "larger."

Comment: Note $\sqrt{\sqrt x} = x^{\frac 14}$ is where your intuitions comes from.  But $\sqrt{x \sqrt x}$ has an extra $x$ in it.  But there is more than one way to do things:  $\sqrt{x \sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt x} = \sqrt{\sqrt{x^2*x}} = \sqrt{\sqrt{x^3}} = (x^3)^{\frac 14} = x^{\frac 34}$

Comment: this split also $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{x}\times\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is $\sqrt{x\sqrt x}= m$

Then $m^2 = x\sqrt x$.

So $(m^2)^2 = (x\sqrt x)^2 = x^2*(\sqrt x)^2 = x^2*x = x^3$

So $m^4 = x^3$ and so

$m = \sqrt[4]{x^3} = x^{\frac 34}$

....

The book did it this way:

$\sqrt{x\sqrt x} = (x\cdot x^{\frac 12})^{\frac 12}=$

$(x^1\cdot x^{\frac 12})^{\frac 12} =$

$(x^{1+ \frac 12})^{\frac 12} =$

$(x^{\frac 32})^{\frac 12} =$ (this is where the $\frac 32$ came from.  $1+\frac 12 = \frac 32$).

$x^{\frac 32\cdot \frac 12} = x^{\frac 34}$.

......

Note: $\sqrt{\sqrt x} = x^{\frac 14}$ is where your intuitions comes from.  But $\sqrt{x \sqrt x}$ has an extra $x$ in it.  But there is more than one way to do things:  $\sqrt{x \sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt x} = \sqrt{\sqrt{x^2*x}} = \sqrt{\sqrt{x^3}} = (x^3)^{\frac 14} = x^{\frac 34}$

Comment: So, why is $\[\left ( {x}\cdot {x}^{1/2} \right )^{1/2}\]$ not $\left ( {x}^{1/2}\cdot {x}^{1/2} \right )$?

Comment: Do both x's not share the same exponent and index? And why does that switch to addition?

Comment: @Nathaniel You have to distribute the exponent to both terms. $$(x\cdot x^{1/2})^{1/2}=x^{1/2}\cdot x^{(1/2)(1/2)}=x^{1/2}\cdot x^{1/4}=x^{(1/2)+(1/4)}=x^{3/4}.$$

Comment: I'm completely fine on that part. But I cannot understand why the equation is not written $\sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{x} = x^{1/2}\cdot x^{1/2}$.

I'm sorry for being obtuse, but I cannot wrap my head around why that first x root is not the exact same thing as the second root. There should be an invisible 2 above the first root serving as the index, and an invisible 1 exponent above the x. And the same should be true for the second x root. Then we should be multiplying them. 

Why is that not the case?If a root is within another root, do they have some other property?Are we not multiplying?

Comment: @Nathaniel I think what you're missing is that the second $\sqrt{x}$ is under another layer of square root as well. So $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x}}$ is not the same thing as $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}$ although they look almost identical; instead, $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x}}$ is the same as $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$. The bigger square root also encapsulates the second term.

Comment: $(a\cdot b)^{\frac 12} = a^{\frac 12}b^{\frac 12}$ and if $a = x$ and $b = \sqrt{x}$ then $(x\cdot x^{\frac 12})^{\frac 12} = (x)^{\frac 12}(x^{\frac 12})^{\frac 12}$.

Comment: I can't wrap me head around why you think the first term under the root, which is $x$, should be the same thing as the second term under the root wihich is $\sqrt x$.  As you know, $x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are not the same thing.  So we are you treating them as though they are.

Comment: "Do both x's not share the same exponent and index?"  No.  They absolutely do not.  And now I think I see your confusion.  You are confusing $x\cdot x^{\frac 12}$ with $(x \cdot x)^{\frac 12}$.  Those are two *entirely* differenth things.  When you have an $ab^k$ the $k$ only applies to the $b$ it does *not* apply to the $a$.  So when you have $x \cdot x^{\frac 12}$ then $\frac 12$ *only* applies to the second $x$. The first $x$ is a $x^1$.  $x\cdot x^{\frac 12} = x^1\cdot x^{\frac 12}= x^{1+\frac 12}$.

Comment: "If a root is within another root, do they have some other property?Are we not multiplying? "  We are doing that.  $\sqrt[2]{x^1\cdot x^{\frac 12}} = x^{1\cdot \frac 12}\cdot x^{\frac 12 \cdot \frac 12}$.  That's multiplying.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$xx^{1/2}=x^1x^{1/2}=x^{1+1/2}=x^{3/2} $$

therefore

$$\sqrt{x\sqrt{x}}=\left(xx^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}=\left(x^1x^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}=\left(x^{3/2}\right)^{1/2}=x^{3/4}$$

Answer (score 1):

What you're thinking of is $\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}=x^{1/4}.$ However, by exponent laws, the expression you have is actually equal to $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{x^{3/2}}=x^{3/4}$